# form async validation when updateOn is blur, to subscribe statusChanges or valueChanges

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-form-validation

I am using form async validation with `updatOn: 'blur'` in my Angular7 application.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9r2qqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

in this situation, I need to check if the name is unique(async validation).

```
this.myForm.get('name').statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
    if (status === 'VALID') {
        // to save the name to database.
    } else {
        // to show some errors.
    }
});
```

question is, where to put this code?

**Current way**

I tried this,in child component

```
@Input()
set myForm(myForm: FormGroup) {
  this._myForm = myForm;
  this.myForm.get('name').statusChanges.subscribe(status => {    // to subscribe statusChanges here.
    if (status === 'VALID') {
        // to save the name to database.
    } else {
        // to show some errors.
    }
  });
}

get myForm() {
  return this._myForm;
}


_myForm: FormGroup
```

it worked. But I have at least 10 attributs to do form validation, this will add too many codes to this `@Input() set myForm() {}`, so I need to do this in another function.

So, I quit to subscribe statusChange in the `@Input` attribute. if not here, where should I do this?

And I can't subscribe statusChange in `ngOnInit`, cause value is undefined in `ngOnInit`.

Anyone helps me pls.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes,but still, I need the validation result to decide which thing should I do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `directive` in this case - Create a directive and add in the necessary `input` fields

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicValidation]'
})
export class DynamicValidationDirective {

  constructor(private control: NgControl) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.control && this.control!= undefined) {
      this.control.statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
        // Your logic will go here
      });
    }       
  }
}
```

Now just add the `directive` in the specific input field

**Input**

```
<input [formControlName]="controlName"
                         type="text"
                         dynamicValidation        //Added the directive
                         class="form-control form-control-sm" />
```

Now all the input fields will be tagged with a subscription and when the status changes the specific input value will get updated respectively

Hope this helps you - Thanks !!

Comment: Your ways worked, but I got a question confusing me. I used data-binding in directive,```@Input() control: FormGroup;```,  in template, ```<input type="text" formControlName="name" dynamicValidation [control]="rowData"```. But the data-binding works twice. First time, it gets the previous value, second time it gets the changed value

Comment: Yeah first time when the page loads the subscribe will get triggered and later when ever the status changed the subscribe will get triggered - if you want to avoid first subscribe and to process your code only when the status changes - you can use `control.touched` property inside your subscribe - so it will allow only when the control is touched - hope it helps

Comment: No, it's not because of that. I set the validation ```updateOn: 'blur'```. The data-binding works twice after the validation done. I get the previous value and chaned value after the ```blur``` happens

Comment: in the directive I did this: ```this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('valueChange:', this.control.value.name);
    });
    this.control.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
      if (status === 'VALID') {
        console.log('statusChange:', this.rowControl.value.name);
      } else {
        console.log('validation failed');
      }
    });``` The output is:```statusChange: previousName; valueChange: changedName; statusChange: changedName;```

Comment: Then is better to use `valueChanges` instead of `statusChanges`in your case - But make sure `valueChanges` will trigger for every change in input